# FPDF font error on production server But working on local server

Tags: php, pdf, fonts, fpdf

Warning: include(timesb.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php on line 1140

Warning: include(): Failed opening 'timesb.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/usr/share/php') in /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php on line 1140

Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: FPDF error: Could not include font definition file in /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php:271 Stack trace: #0 /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php(1142): FPDF->Error('Could not inclu...') #1 /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php(459): FPDF->_loadfont('timesb.php') #2 /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php(507): FPDF->AddFont('times', 'B') #3 /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/application.php(259): FPDF->SetFont('times', 'B', 12) #4 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/tn_poly_lateral/candidate-portal/application/fpdf.php on line 271

This fpdf error shows on production server But when I execute file on locally using xampp everything works fine and pdf is downloading. Anyone help to resolve the problem

Comment: Your PHP include path is different between the servers. On your local installation the location of the fonts directory for fPDF is in the include path but it isn't on your production server.

Answer (score 0):

depending on your error it appears that there is missing files
timesb.php doesn't exist on your hosting you can check on your hosting search that file if it doesn't exist add it

Comment: does the php version is the same as your localhost

Comment: @Aravindanvaithialingam "the file exists" But maybe not where it should be. Don't you think it's an important information to give?

Comment: it should be in the right place or it will not work at all so try to put each file in it's emplacement and check your PHP compatibility